# Selenide PDF Download Cannot download file: proxy server is not started

Tags: selenium, pdf, proxy, automated-tests, selenide

I'm having some troubles understanding the problem I am facing with a proxy error while trying to download a pdf file. I am behind a company firewall, and as you can see I've tried setting proxy but I still get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot download file: proxy server is not started
```

How do I solve this, what does this mean exactly? Google searches didn't offer me too much valuable info or I haven't been able to figure it out correctly, and hints would be greatly appreciated.

What I tried:

```
Configuration.proxyEnabled = true;
Configuration.fileDownload = FileDownloadMode.PROXY;
Configuration.proxyHost = "32.453.324.435";
Configuration.proxyPort = 8080;
File file = $(applicationList.printButton).download();
```

Also this:

```
String url = "http://32.453.324.435/";
System.setProperty("wdm.proxy", url);    // url as "http://host:port"
System.setProperty("wdm.proxyUser", url);
System.setProperty("wdm.proxyPass", url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by setting Configuration properties in the @BeforeAll setup method by, it seems that setting downloadsFolder helped

```
Configuration.downloadsFolder = "/src/pdfs";
Configuration.proxyHost = "32.453.324.435";
Configuration.proxyPort = 8080;
Configuration.proxyEnabled = true;
Configuration.fileDownload = FileDownloadMode.PROXY;
```